# Check if an array has an object with a certain property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
const arr = [
{ puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: [] }, 
{ puzzle: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] }
]
```

And I have an object:

```
const element = { puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: ["1"]}
```

Im trying to see if element.puzzle is a value for a property of any of the objects in the array - **in this particular example**
`element.puzzle === arr[0].puzzle`, but a few methods I tried give the wrong result, so obviously I`m wrong...

array.some() method gives wrong result

```
arr.some(item => item.puzzle === element.puzzle) // gives false
arr.find(item=>item.puzzle === element.puzzle) //gives undefined
```

Comment: @ControlAltDel that function doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

For each item in the array, check to see if at least one has a puzzle that has the same length and matches every index/value in the element's puzzle.

```js
const
  arr = [
    { puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: [] }, 
    { puzzle: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] }
  ],
  element = { puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: ["1"]}

const arrHasPuzzle = arr.some(({ puzzle }) =>
  puzzle.length === element.puzzle.length &&
  puzzle.every((e, i) => e === element.puzzle[i]));

console.log(arrHasPuzzle); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the both of the puzzles are different instances of arrays. And since arrays are objects they're treated as different values when comparing equality, even if they contain the same values.

```js
[1,2,3] === [1,2,3] //false
```

Instead, you're going to have to compare the values of every element in both arrays with each other to tell if they're "equivalent".

```js
arr.some(item => item.puzzle.every((e, i) => element.puzzle[i] === e))
arr.find(item => item.puzzle.every((e, i) => element.puzzle[i] === e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Polywhirl has delivered a very concise and effective solution. However, it will return `false` whenever the `.puzzle` elements of `arr[i]` and `element` are not ordered identically. Below snippet shows how you can fix that problem:

```js
const
  arr = [
    { puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: [] }, 
    { puzzle: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] }
  ],
  element = { puzzle: [1,4,3,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: ["1"]}

element.pzl=element.puzzle.slice(0).sort();
const arrHasPuzzle = arr.some(({ puzzle }) =>
  puzzle.length === element.pzl.length &&
  puzzle.slice(0).sort().every((e, i) => e === element.pzl[i]));

console.log(arrHasPuzzle); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution without using inbuilt operators:**

```js
const arr = [
  { puzzle: [1, 3, 4, 8, 0, 2, 7, 6, 5], children: ["1"] },
  { puzzle: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }
];

const element = { puzzle: [1, 3, 4, 8, 0, 2, 7, 6, 5], children: ["1"] };

function findElement(arr, element) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const currentElement = arr[i];
    if (
      currentElement.puzzle &&
      JSON.stringify(currentElement.puzzle) === JSON.stringify(element.puzzle) &&
      JSON.stringify(currentElement.children) === JSON.stringify(element.children)
    ) {
      return i; // Return the index if the element found
    }
  }
  return -1; // Return -1 if the element is not found
}

const index = findElement(arr, element);

if (index !== -1) {
  console.log(`Element found at index ${index}`);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[index]))
} else {
  console.log('Element not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#some()` and `Array#every()` as follows:

```
const m arr.some(
  item => item.puzzle.every((e,i) => e === element.puzzle[i])
);
```

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [
  { puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: [] }, 
  { puzzle: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] }
];

const element = { puzzle: [1,3,4,8,0,2,7,6,5], children: ["1"]};

const m = arr.some(
  item => item.puzzle.every((e,i) => e === element.puzzle[i])
);

console.log( m );
```